android bottom navigation bar buttons invisible if statusbar white
In android 9 , when trying to set bottom navigation bar (that has 3 button back, home , another button) to white, the buttons are invisible. I beleive it has white color, and when background color is white, it is invisble.
my code is
  getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR);
    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.white));
  

I beleive there may be some issue into themes, but not sure. I have tried same code into new simple solution, it works fine and the buttons are gray with white background. But into my big app, it can not figure what is the issue.
kindly advise what will be start point.
Thanks..
